# Анимация разрушения картинки

Tags: css, jquery, css3, html5, css-animation

Всем привет, никак не могу найти решение подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, задача такая есть к примеру картинка  и нужно как бы разделить ее на кусочки и что бы они разлетелись в разные стороны, можно ли это сделать как-то через css, jQuery или может какая-то либа есть?

Comment: Есть библиотека imgexplode.js для jQuery. Она позволяет взрывать/собирать изображения. Описание можно посмотреть здесь: [Create An Image Explosion Effect In jQuery - imgexplode.js](https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Create-An-Image-Explosion-Effect-In-jQuery-imgexplode-js.html) [Демо](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Create-An-Image-Explosion-Effect-In-jQuery-imgexplode-js/)